# What’s the meaning of “split wide open”

Tags: idioms

What’s the meaning of “split wide open”??
I’m confused and I found it in this sentence: “everything I knew was split wide open”

> Source ([UCLA magazine](http://magazine.ucla.edu/depts/quicktakes/the-time-has-come/))
> *“The world cracked down the middle,” she wrote later in a preface to a special edition of the book, “and everything I knew was split wide open. ...*

Comment: I've added the source. Personally I can't see how you can have a problem with metaphoric ***split wide open*** if you didn't have a problem with *exactly* the same metaphoric reference as used to start this very sentence. What did you think the writer meant by saying the world ***cracked down the middle***?

Answer (score 3):

If you split a rock or a log or a fruit open, you can see what is inside.
[image]

If you split something *wide* open then the inside is revealed even more.

[image]

The author is using a metaphor.  Probably it means that the knowledge the person had, was broken into fragments. What they had always believed to be reality turned out not to be true.

Comment: _They no longer knew what they thought had been true_. What's that supposed to mean? In what relation does the NP _what they thought had been true_ stand to the rest of the sentence; and is this, by the way, a good choice of a metaphor @Chasly-supports Monica?

Comment: @user405662 - Thanks for your comment. I had already rewritten the sentence when you commented. No, I don't think it is a particularly good metaphor.